# Laravel custom string as field

Tags: php, laravel

How would I convert the following statement into laravel's eloquent or Query builder:

Select *, 'admin' as type from users.

its the ***'admin' as type*** is where im having problem in converting it on laravel. Thanks

[image: screenshot of the query and result]

Comment: try this `$users = DB::table('users')->selectRaw("*, 'admin' as type")->get();`

Comment: You can use this also. Users::where('type','admin')->get();

Comment: error on result. Invalid column name '"admin"'

Comment: What is the name of your column.

Comment: @FaizanFayaz its a custom string added to a query and i named it as TYPE

Comment: does `DB::select("select *, 'admin' as type from users")` return anything?

Comment: @lagbox This solves it. Thank you.

Comment: @jundrie Do you absolutely needs to use **type** in your query ? You can also create a your custom **type** attribute in Laravel that return the admin value.

Comment: I have a unique scenario which generates a report from two different applications. I needed that TYPE field in creating a common field from multiple tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather figure out why MSSQL is handling it that way, or the adapter but since that raw SELECT directly on the connection works, you can do that with Eloquent as well:

```
App\User::fromQuery("select *, 'admin' as type from users");
```

You will have a Collection of models hydrated from that result.

Answer (score 2):

Using query builder your can try it like this

```
$users = DB::table('users')->selectRaw("*, 'admin' AS type")->get();
```

And if you have `User` model then

```
$users = User::selectRaw("*, 'admin' AS type")->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But both this shows this error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name '"admin"'

Comment: are you using SqlServer ?

Comment: does the sql working directly in your `mssql` client ?

Comment: Yes. it displayed results if I run that query directly on my database.

Comment: ive added a picture of the native query and result for your reference

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by lagbox. This query returns what I need. Thank  you all.

`DB::select("select *, 'admin' as type from users")`

Comment: I posted another answer that was dependent upon the question i had asked